# How to decrypt the c program?

Tags: vim, vi

I am using linux operating system in my pc and I am using the terminal to run my c programs. To compile, run and exit from my program I should type :x (colon and small x). By my mistake I had entered the key :X (colon and capital X). It shows the message like "Warning : Using a week encryption method. encryption key:" I have entered a encryption key. now it's totally encrypted and I can not use the code. Because it shows full of errors while compiling.
I don't know that how to decrypt my program. If anyone knows the solution please help me to solve that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the C tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Vi as your editor (`:x` is a bit of a give-away).  From [this page](https://tipsandtricks4it.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/how-to-cryptdecrypt-a-file-with-vi/):

### Crypt

Open the file using vi, type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, enter the key (this key will be the password to see the crypted file) and then save and exit with <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The file will be crypted.

You can use:

```
vi -x yourfile
```

to do the same thing.

### Decrypt

To decrypt just the way you encrypted the file.

Open the file using vi, type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, enter the key and after that the file will be visible and writable. If you close and save your file by <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> the file will be still crypted.